# Checking whether a product can be added to cart or not

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, inventory

We've recently allowed out of stock products to be shown on the front end.

Now I want to display an *"out of stock*" image alongside the wishlist image.

I went into: **app/design/frontend/default/default/template/catalog/product/view** and tried:

```
<ul>
<?php if(!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
    <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/out_of_stock.jpg') ?>" /></li>
<?php endif; ?>
</ul>
```

In both **addto.phtml** and **addtocart.phtml** template files, but it display the image on both in-stock and out of stock items for some reason. This is strange because I know this is the right template file and the right method. I also cleared cache with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will work if you fix the typo. When something is `salable` it is for sale. "Saleable" is not an english word.

E.g.:

```
<?php if(!$_product->isSalable()): ?>
    <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/out_of_stock.jpg') ?>" /></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:

```
<?php if(!$_product->isSalable()): ?>
   <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/out_of_stock.jpg') ?>" /></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

It is actually not the product directly that is in stock or not, but a separate entity the stock item ( from the model 'cataloginventory/stock_item').

So to check if the product is marked as in stock or not use:

```
$_product->getStockItem()->getIsInStock()
```

rather than

```
$_product->isSaleable()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try below Code.

```
<?php if(!$_product->getQty()<0): ?>
   <li><img src="<?php echo $this->getSkinUrl('images/out_of_stock.jpg') ?>" /></li>
<?php endif; ?>
```

The Condition will be based on Quantity. so it will come only for out of stock Products.